# Angular binding with escape characters

Tags: angular

I want to display a string value that treats escape characters for what they are. But through default binding these characters just cleared. Setting string value as `innerText` does what I want but I hope there's more convenient way to do it. Do you know any?

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xuzfwc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p [innerText]="testText"></p>
```

Still inner text, but cleaner.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Will accept the answer when I'll be able to

Answer (score 2):

Inner text in template, as @Yuriy suggested, or:

```
<pre>{{ testText }}</pre>
```

Comment: another awesome way I didn't know. Thank you very much